# React - rotate chevron on click

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, rotation, transition

I am trying to rotate a chevron when clicking it by using state to toggle a className, but I can't get it to work. The component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const FilterGroup = () => {
    const [rotateChevron, setRotateChevron] = useState(false);

    const handleRotate = () => setRotateChevron(!rotateChevron);

    return (
             <ExpandMoreIcon className={"filters__chevron " + rotateChevron ? "rotate" : null} onClick={handleRotate} />
           )
    }

export default FilterGroup;
```

This is the CSS :

```
.filters__chevron {
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 2 linear;
}

.filters__chevron.rotate {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const FilterGroup = () => {
    const [rotateChevron, setRotateChevron] = useState(false);

    const handleRotate = () => setRotateChevron(!rotateChevron);

    const rotate = rotateChevron ? "rotate(180deg)" : "rotate(0)"

    return (
             <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ transform: rotate, transition: "all 0.2s linear" }} onClick={handleRotate} />
      )
}

export default FilterGroup;
```

Comment: Works perfect in combination with reactstrap card

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
className={`filters__chevron ${rotateChevron ? "rotate" :''}`}
```

Comment: No joy unfortunately

Comment: Go to inspect tab, and inspect and check what is the css class that appears.

Comment: It's rotating now, but without the transition time. It's just doing it instantly.

Comment: Okay. That's another issue. You may want to use transition-duration:0.5s; to achieve that. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Got it working! Answer below. Thanks for the help :)